# Can I Airplay from one mac to another? (or from iOS to Mac)

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, airplay, remote-control

I have a Mac connected to a large 27 inch monitor. I want to be able to remotely push audio and video to it. The source device can be an iPhone, iPad, or another Mac.

(Imagine a dorm room situation, where I want to play Netflix, or other media on the big screen, from my phone, and use that phone as a remote)

As a developer, I've come across some bugs in the past that make it appear that an OSX could act as an Airplay *Target*.

Is there any way I can make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

You can AirPlay from your iOS device to your Mac using [Reflector 2](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/). This works on macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

### [Elmedia Player](https://www.elmedia-video-player.com)

The app Elmedia Player turns your Mac into an AirPlay receiver, for both audio and video. It has a free mode and works on macOS Sierra (10.12) and newer.

1. Download and install the app
2. Open Elmedia Player
3. Go to the app preferences (press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to get there quickly)
4. Select the Streaming tab
5. Finally, select AirPlay in the sidebar and check the box next to AirPlay Service to turn it on

[image]